# How can I tell when Turbo Boost is active on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I have one of the core i7 MacBooks, and I'm wondering if there is a way to see when Turbo Boost is active (other than the fact that the laptop gets really hot and the fan kicks on).

I use iStat to monitor CPU activity, but that doesn't show Turbo Boost activity.

Comment: I always think of KITT and Michael Knight when I read 'Turbo boost' - http://i160.photobucket.com/albums/t165/andygarand/kp13.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's 2 utilities that could provide that info,

- one from Intel called **MacCPUID** (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-maccpuid/)
- other called **CPU-X** (http://netkas.org/?p=72) rather outdated

Hope this helps.

Karl

Comment: The MacCPUID *always* shows that my CPU is clocked at 2.3 GHZ. But in fact it should change from time to time and go from 1.8GHZ-2.8GHz. Not really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Check out the [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget). It provides info about the processor frequency in GHz and Processor Power in W.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: On my Mid 2010 iMac with a core i7 the installer balks, saying "Intel® Power Gadget only supports 2nd generation Intel® Core™ processors and later."

Comment: ver 3 downloaded from here worked find on my Macbook Pro Retina 2015 https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20

Answer (score 1):

with a mac pro13" 2013 retina (2.4GHz, 2.9GHz turbo boost) this works and I can clearly see turbo boost kicking in with very tight numerical code and taking the cpu up to 2.88GHz. With this code I am getting ~ 10.22Gflops from a single core using SSE (peak would be 11.6Gflops at 2.9GHz)